# Can I get a list of the symbols passed to attr_accessor in a class when inspecting?

Tags: ruby, class, metaprogramming

Assuming I have defined a class with accessors defined using `attr_accessor`:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :alpha, :beta, :gamma

  def initialize
    self.alpha = 1
  end
end
```

Is there a built-in method that gives the list of method names passed to an `attr_accessor` call? Or do I have to define a constant with the symbols, and pass it to `attr_accessor`?

Comment: do you mean `@alpha`?

Comment: @zishe No, the OP probably means `self.alpha = 1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "define a CONST with the symbols, and pass it to attr_accessor"?

Comment: Please clarify, preferably with an example that includes the desired result.

Comment: BTW: your code assigns a local variable named `alpha` but never does anything with it.

Comment: I propose this be reopened because an answer provide is correct.  What i wanted to do was not possible, and @JörgWMittag explained that well in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in method. Your solution of storing the method names at creation time will work, as long as you know in advance and can control what the method names are.

In my answer to [a different but similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439116/get-all-variables-defined-through-attr-accessor-without-overriding-attr-acces), I showed how to get the names of the methods dynamically, after the fact, using `TracePoint`. I've updated it below to include `:attr_reader` and `:attr_writer`.

```
module MethodTracer
  TracePoint.trace(:c_call) do |t|
    if %i[attr_accessor attr_writer attr_reader].include?(t.method_id)
      t.self.extend(MethodTracer)

      methods = t.self::Methods ||= []
      MethodTracer.send(:define_method, :method_added) {|m| methods << m }
    end
  end

  TracePoint.trace(:c_return) do |t|
    if %i[attr_accessor attr_writer attr_reader].include?(t.method_id)
      MethodTracer.send(:remove_method, :method_added)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :a
  attr_reader :b
  attr_writer :c

  def foo; end
end

Foo::Methods # => [:a, :a=, :b, :c=]
```

I've stored the method names in the `Methods` constant, but obviously you can store them wherever is most convenient for you.

Defining/removing `method_added` on `MethodTracer` ensures that you don't clobber any `Foo.method_added` you've defined yourself. This methodology, however, does require that if you define `Foo.method_added` before your calls to `attr_*`, you will need to call `super` inside it. Otherwise you will skip the temporary `method_added` defined by `MethodTracer`.

Comment: This is really a compelling solution.  Thank you so much for posting it.  I'm changing yours to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Grep an Instance for Setter Methods

One way to do this would be to grep an instance of the class for setters. For example:

```
A.new.methods.grep(/\p{alnum}+=\z/)
#=> [:alpha=, :beta=, :gamma=]
```

Comment: That won't necessarily produce the correct names because setters can be defined manually.  Whether that makes a difference to the op, who knows?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Methods generated by `attr_accessor`, `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` are indistinguishable from ones written by hand. In fact, they *must* be indistinguishable from ones written by hand!

Say, you have a simple `attr_accessor`, but you later want to refactor it to do something more intelligent (e.g. caching). This is a purely internal change, a client *must not* be able to observe the difference, otherwise it would be a breach of encapsulation!

If you simply want a list of setters, that's easy enough: setters are methods whose name ends with an `=` sign:

```
A.public_instance_methods(false).grep(/=$/)
# => [:alpha=, :beta=, :gamma=]
```

For getters, it's trickier: any method that doesn't take an argument *could* be a getter, but it could also be a side-effecting method (e.g. [`Array#clear`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-clear)):

```
A.public_instance_methods(false).select {|m| 
  A.public_instance_method(m).arity.zero? 
}
# => [:alpha, :beta, :gamma]
```