# Get all variables defined through `attr_accessor` without overriding `attr_accessor`

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am setting some trace code on my program, and would like to know which methods are defined through `attr_accessor`. Using `TracePoint`, I can detect when `attr_accessor` is called, but I don't know how to get it to tell me the arguments it received. Any ideas?

Comment: You can just get _all_ instance variables. If this is not good enough, then you'll have to instrument attr_accessor in one way or another. No way to avoid this.

Comment: Does it matter whether method was defined using `attr_accessor` or you are looking for methods that are accessor methods of instance variables?

Comment: attr_accessor is what I am after. The rest I can get easily with TracePoint.

Answer (score 8):

In the question title, you asked for a list of variables, but this answers the question body, which asked for a list of the methods defined.

This method doesn't bother checking instance variables, which will have noise introduced if you begin manually updating or creating other instance variables.

```
module MethodTracer
  TracePoint.trace(:c_call) do |t|
    if (t.method_id == :attr_accessor)
      t.self.extend(MethodTracer)

      methods = t.self::Methods ||= []
      MethodTracer.send(:define_method, :method_added) {|m| methods << m }
    end
  end

  TracePoint.trace(:c_return) do |t|
    if (t.method_id == :attr_accessor)
      MethodTracer.send(:remove_method, :method_added)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :a, :b
  attr_accessor :c

  def foo; end
end

Foo::Methods # => [:a, :a=, :b, :b=, :c, :c=]
```

I've stored the method names in the `Methods` constant, but obviously you can store them wherever is most convenient for you.

Defining/removing `method_added` on `MethodTracer` ensures that you don't clobber any `Foo.method_added` you've defined yourself. This methodology, however, does require that if you define `Foo.method_added` before your calls to `attr_accessor`, you will need to call `super` inside it. Otherwise you will skip the temporary `method_added` defined by `MethodTracer`.

Comment: As a side note, I spent some time trying to figure out how to use `TracePoint` to get the names of the methods as passed to `attr_accessor`. I found it to be quite impossible.

Comment: I tried to. And so did the OP. That was the whole point of the question. And only you reached the solution.

Comment: Amazing stuff. I also had traces on c_call and a check if the method is attr_accessor, then got stuck there. Calling #parameters on `method(:attr_accessor)` tells me it received some (returns `[[:rest]]`), but no idea how to get that, since it receives a traditional splat argument.

Comment: Very nice answer, I learned something new because of this answer

Comment: The problem is that I was running it in IRB. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `obj.methods()` to find all the methods available on the instance (inc methods from superclasses), and `obj.methods(false)` to get only the method defined on current singleton object. I'm not sure its possible to detect if these methods where created via `attr_accessor` though

Comment: Then this doesn't really answer the question, does it? :)